# Android TableRow background

Tags: android, layout, onclick

I have a problem with a TableRow, which I add dynamically.

```
private void addRow(String body) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        TableRow row = (TableRow) inflater.inflate(R.layout.customrow,null);
        TextView name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.customName);
        name.setText(body);                        
        row.setOnLongClickListener(this);       
    }
```

I would like this row to change color upon `onClick` and `onLongClick`.

Code in the `customrow.xml` file is:

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/tableRow1" 
       android:layout_gravity="center" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:gravity="center_vertical" 
       android:onClick="showOnClick">    
    <TextView android:id="@+id/customName"
        android:textSize="25px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_weight="5">
    </TextView>
</TableRow>
```

I have tried to use `android:background="@drawable/clickedbackground"`with the row but it is not working.

Code in the `clickedbackground.xml` file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">        
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/custom" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/custom" />
</selector>
```

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong (color/custom is defined in another xml which works)?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding

```
<resources>
 <style name="row" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
     <item name="android:background">@drawable/rows</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

in styles.xml and setting

```
style="@style/row"
```

in the TableRow did the job.

where the rows.xml in the drawable is

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
    android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@color/blue" />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@color/custom" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@color/white" />
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are creating object for `tablerow` named row. and you have also  `clickedbackground.xml`  file. just use below code in `addRow` method.

`row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.clickedbackground);`

I think it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your `addRow()` method you're inflating the row but you're not adding it to any parent layout, and as `row` is a local variable I think you're not doing it anywhere else, is it a copy/paste problem?

Again, your `customrow.xml` might be not working because the opening `TableRow` tag lacks the closing `>`, but it might be copy/paste problem.

Using `android:background="@drawable/bg"` with `bg` being a selector is a common pattern and it should work. You might want to simplify your selector: you don't need to specify all the states for each item and all the combinations. It works with a "first match", so this will do the job:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">        
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/custom" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/custom" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Also, notice that selected and focused [are two different states](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#item-element), focused being the one you get when moving around with dpad.

If this didn't help please specify what "is not working" means: what do you expect? what's happening instead?

Comment: Okay. There are a couple copy/paste problems:) The row is getting added in the addRow(), so this is a copy/paste problem. As is the missing > in the xml. I have tried with your xml, but that didn't help either. The problem is that the row does not change color when pressed. The row is there and working as i should except the changing color thing.

Comment: @Bastaix I'm sorry but then I don't know what might be wrong. This should work even without an onClick listener. Oh wait, try putting `android:clickable="true"` in `TableRow` tag.

Comment: No that did not help either. I will have to continue my search. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

do not forget to add to the style

```
<item name="android:focusable">true</item>
        <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
```

Otherwise, you will not be able to use the states of a rowLayout.