# TableRow background image

Tags: android, background-image, tablerow

Is it possible to set an image as the background of a table row?

I found various ways of setting the color, i need to make it an image.

If not, how would I go about achieving the same result?

below is my table layout:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey"
android:layout_gravity="center">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/matchRow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="100.0">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/teamAName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="TeamA"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="30"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/teamAIcon"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_btn_speak_now"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_weight="10"/>
        <TableLayout>
            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/startTime"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:text="19 October 2016"
                    android:layout_column="3"
                    android:layout_weight="25"/>
                />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/endtime"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:text="19 October 2016"
                    android:layout_column="3"
                    android:layout_weight="25"/>
                />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/teamBIcon"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_btn_speak_now"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:layout_column="4"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/teamBName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="TeamB"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_column="5"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: [Does this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325745/android-tablerow-background) work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to the question:**

Yes is possible:

```
          <TableRow 
             android:background="@drawable/your_image">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/endtime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="19 October 2016"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_weight="25"/>

          </TableRow>
```

or:

```
 TableRow tbr1 = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.tbr_1);
 tbr1.setBackground(yourDrawableImage);
```

**Based on the last comment:**

> the image is a url to a image on the web, and i need to set it
>   programatically

```
  <TableRow 
     android:id="@+id/tbr_1">

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/endtime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="19 October 2016"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_weight="25"/>

  </TableRow>
```

**Download external image:**

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Bitmap to Drawable:**

```
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), getBitmapFromURL("your image src));
```

**Set the background:**

```
 TableRow tbr1 = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.tbr_1);
 tbr1.setBackground(d);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: the image is a url to a image on the web, and i need to set it programatically

Comment: Thats another question ;)

Comment: works like a charm... I think the part i was missing from all of this `Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(`, i was not sure how to convert a bitmap to a drawable. Thanx for the help, i marked it as the answer, and will award bounty as soon as i am allowed to.